# The use of that, those

Tags: grammar

- Their physiological arousal also declined quickly to the same levels as **those** of the control subjects.
- For example, high noise levels interfered with the performance of subjects who were required to monitor three dials at a time, a task not unlike **that** of an aeroplane pilot or an air-traffic controller

In the 1st sentence, does the word **those** replaces for **physiological arousa**l to avoid repetition?
 And in the 2nd sentence, **that** replace for which word?

Comment: No; 'those' replaces 'physiological arousal **levels**'.

Comment: "that" replaces "the task" in your second sentence.

Comment: Thank you everyone. but why  'those' replaces 'physiological arousal levels",  not replaces 'physiological arousal'

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in the first instance, "those of" could be replaced with "the physiological arousal levels of".

In the second instance, "that of" refers to the task, generally.  It's not very well worded, in my opinion, but you could replace "that of" with "the type of tasks performed by an".  The reason I think it's not well worded is that you have a single task in the first instance, but pilots and air-traffic controllers don't just perform this single task:  they perform **many** tasks, including monitoring many different dials or instruments at once, but also doing other things (such as flying the plane).  So, it's not a straight swap, if you know what I mean.